# row id from database

Tags: android

i am trying to do a query of my database for a string lets call it "Test" and then find out what row that particular string is in and save that number to use. I thought i had this figured out before but now it is not working for some reason and i get an error saying no such column "Test".

here is my code

```
public String getRow(String value){

    ContactDB db = new ContactDB(this);
    db.open();
    Cursor curs = db.getId(value);
    String test = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(db.NAME));
    curs.close();
    Log.v("Contact", "Row ID: " + test);
    db.close();
    return test;
}
```

"Test" is sent into that as value

this is in my database

```
//---retrieve contact id---
public Cursor getId(String where){
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ID},where,null,null,null,null);
    if (c != null) 
        c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

i dont remember changing anything from when i first tested it so i dont know why it wont work now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 errors that i could notice:

1. In the query

   Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ID},where,null,null,null,null);

only the ID column is selected whereas you are trying to fetch details for column NAME

```
String test = curs.getString(curs.getColumnIndex(db.NAME));
```

include the name column as well in the select clause : something like

```
Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ID,NAME},where,null,null,null,null);
```

1. In the where clause you need to write the condition string excluding "where"
   in your case String where contains value "Test". Hence the filter condition should be as

   String whereClasue = NAME + " = '" + where + "'";

The query should be something like this:

```
public Cursor getId(String where){
     Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ID,PHONE_NUMBER,NAME},NAME + " = '" + where + "'",null,null,null,null);

    if (c != null) 
        c.moveToFirst();
    return c;
}
```

Comment: changed my query to what you said
    Cursor c = db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {ID,PHONE_NUMBER,NAME},NAME + "=" + where,null,null,null,null);

but it still does the same thing

Comment: did you change the where string as i mentioned above ?

Comment: I must be confused as to what you mean by the where string then. I thought you meant in the query change where to NAME + "=" + where. Is that what you meant?

Comment: i have modified my ans. hope that helps.

Comment: ok it now executes the query but it gives me an error java.lang.IllegalStateException: get field slot from row 0 col -1 failed

Comment: I am sorry. I forgot to incorporate your changes in the query.Changed again.